# Docker Setup for Magento cloud - Elasticsearch issue faced

Tags: magento2, docker, magento-cloud

- I have tried to setup the Magento cloud project using docker desktop preview. And I am using Mac M1 chip.
- Docker desktop preview installed successfully.
- Followed magento devdocs for docker setup and get the magento cloud projects successfully.
- While trying to execute the docker-compose up -d command and elastic search container throws the below error.

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java": error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 240, exit value: 1

at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)

at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)

at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.flagsFinal(JvmErgonomics.java:114)

at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.finalJvmOptions(JvmErgonomics.java:88)

at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:59)

at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:139)

at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:95)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 240, exit value: 1

at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)

at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:319)

at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:250)

at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, same exception.
I used this version
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2
after change version to docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.1
the problem is solved.
You can search a docker compose file and change the image version to newer